# Is there an advantage for creating a user in firebase cloud functions rather than doing it locally?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Pretty simple question. Is there an advantage/disadvantage for calling `admin.auth().createUser()` in the Firebase cloud functions rather than calling `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` locally on a website? Is one particularly faster or better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is creating their own account on the device, that should be done with the Firebase client SDK.  It will:

- create the account
- or tell them if there is a problem
- sign them into it immediately
- allow your code to request email validation

[Firebase UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui) makes a lot of this trivial to implement.

Creating the account on the backend would require a lot more code to:

- call the function
- pass arguments and send results
- sign into the account on the client

The only real advantage is that your backend can put additional constraints on the email and password used to sign in.  If you're not going to do that, you're just writing a lot of extra code for no benefit.

Comment: What if I have extra validation? Like, when a user signs up, some values are added to the Firestore database. Wouldn't it make sense to put it all together on the server?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to get that done.  Pick the one you prefer.  Stack Overflow isn't really a place to ask for opinions, though if you want to ask another question about tradeoffs between the choices you are consider, that's an option.